# I need to use Powershell to update McAfee AV Scan Engine. I have a script basically there but can't find the approriate cmdlets

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, mcafee

The code I have so far is the following -

```
param(
    [string]$ePOServer,
    [string]$ePOUser,
    [string]$ePOPassword,
    [string]$ePOPort = "8443",
    [switch]$ForceFullPolicyUpdate
)

# Define the functions from the ePowershell module that are needed to connect to and work with your ePO server
function Connect-EpoServer {
}

function Disconnect-EpoServer {
}

# Connect to the ePO server
Connect-EpoServer -Server $ePOServer -User $ePOUser -Password $ePOPassword -Port $ePOPort
```

I need another command after to update the AV Scan engine to the current version, something like Invoke-McAfeeEpoUpdateCheck.

But i'm not sure where to go with this next.
I'm using this as a library - https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ePOwerShell/2.2.0/Content/ePOwerShell.psm1

thanks

Comment: I would advise you look for an alternative approach. The module you linked to includes the following warning: `The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the module is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.` - not a good sign. I see a huge alarm bell while skimming the code too. If your using self-signed certificates on powershell 5 this code will bypass TLS certificate validation for all certificates (line 365) not just your ePO.  This isnt good code.

Comment: It's not clear what you'll gain by doing this via PowerShell rather than the ePolicy Orchestrator GUI. Here's how you could do it via the GUI... https://docs.trellix.com/bundle/security-for-microsoft-exchange-8.8.0-product-guide-epolicy-orchestrator/page/GUID-CC3DF672-2171-4FF5-9971-F7426C0CC97B.html If you did want to try using a script, there's an official Python module for this that you could use to test out ideas before converting the code to PowerShell, as it's all based around REST API calls as far as I can tell. Also, this is worth a look... https://github.com/Kreloc/Posh-ePoAPI